# Do I Use PropTypes if Using Context API

Tags: reactjs

First few months with React here...
I can imagine that I would use prop types for true props coming into a component. But what if I'm getting most of my data from the context api provider as a consumer, do I still need to use prop types? Is there something else I should be doing. This code seems a bit pointless.

```
App.propTypes = {
  context: PropTypes.object,
};
```

I just want to be doing things the right way. I refactored my app to use the context api instead of prop drilling. Which has been nice. Just wasn't sure where proptypes fall with all this.

Hopefully that makes sense.

I previously had something like this in one of my components.

```
 Filters.propTypes = {
  context: PropTypes.object,
   resData: PropTypes.object,
   query: PropTypes.object,
   updateQueryFields: PropTypes.func,
   scrollerBack: PropTypes.func,
   createAnalyticsEvent: PropTypes.func,
   resetEverything: PropTypes.func,
   resetStatus: PropTypes.string,
 };
```

But now almost all of that data is in the context api provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `PropTypes.shape` to specifiy the structure.

E.g.

```
Filters.propTypes = {
    context: PropTypes.shape({
        something: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        anotherThing: PropTypes.string,
        anotherObject: PropTypes.shape({
            foo: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Ah ok. I had to research that a bit. So "shape" is a way to check types within an object, which context is. Thanks. Marking this as the accepted answer. I'm curious if this is what people using the context api are doing, as in, is this the current best practice?

Comment: Ditto. I did something similar and was told to use propTypes only for prop components, which context isn't.